# Insert Image Within Borer using PHP

Tags: php

How can I insert an image within a black line border using php? Thanks for all help!
Here is what I have:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 80);//creates canvas and sets size
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0,0,100,80, $white);
imageline($image, 5,5,5,75, $black);//draws black vertical line
imageline($image, 5,5,95,5, $black);//draws black horizontal line
imageline($image, 5,75,95,75, $black);//draws black horizontal line
imageline($image, 95,5,95,75, $black);//draws black vertical line
//***I now want to insert an image inside the black line border***///  
imagegif($image, "marked5.gif");//creates image
echo "<img src='marked5.gif'>";//prints out my image
```

Comment: first check if `imagegif($image, "marked5.gif");` created your image and image exist in directory then use proper url for src of `<img src='marked5.gif'>` like `http://localhost/marked5.gif`

Comment: why don't you just style the image with css?